# how to install jfreechart on linux is there any website tht can help me?

Tags: java

i have tried many websites it still does not get installed
i have used synaptic package manager also 
also are their any alternatives to drawing graphs in java

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_installation.htm

```
BarChar_AWT.java:1: error: package jfree.chart does not exist
import jfree.chart.*;
```

code

```
import jfree.chart.*;

class BarChar_AWT
{ 
}
```

i am a beginner in java programming

Comment: did you add the jars to the classpath ?

Comment: yes i followed everything tried it 4 times

Comment: then you need to add in which environment you develop and how you compile etc ? Do you use Eclipse, Netbeans etc ? How did you add the jars to classpath etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best guide for the JFreeChart Class Library Installation

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download/jfreechart-1.0.0-install.pdf